# Populate array of object Id's from mongoose sub-schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema

```
    var likedSchema = new Schema({
        counter: {type: Number, default: 0, required: true},
        user: {type: Array, default: [], ref: 'User'}
    });
```

The above schema contains the number of ObjectId's which are likned to user as well as the counter.

```
    var mySchema = new Schema({
        liked: likedSchema,
        name: {type: String, required: true}
    });
```

In above schema i am using the likedSchema

```
        mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
```

These are the two schema defined.
In likedSchema i have multiple objectIds of user records.

By using mySchema i want to populate those records to get the details of all the users.

```
liked: {counter: 1, user:[{"name": 
"smith","_id":"5a437f06b2a00b28ecf217a9"},{"name": 
"john","_id":"5a437f06b2a00b28ecf21192"}];
```

I need to display data in the above format, with user details.
Can any one help me please to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the likedSchema:

```
user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
}]
```

then when querying the database, for example with a findById, use populate on it as follows:

```
MySchema.findById({someId}).populate("liked.user").exec(err, foundObject){
    //if no error, then you have the object with a list of users in the liked object here.
    console.log(foundObject.liked); //obviously in your code, have an if (err) line before this 
}
```

Comment: then mark it correct so the question is considered solved

Comment: @rakan316 I have a similar issue, please if you have a free time you can help me. [Here my post about the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676875/mongoose-connect-two-collections)

Comment: Awesome, does it work to find several users? I mean, for example: `findById({}).populate` or `findById({here a query with several id... }).populate`